# PHP and MYSQL: select values between two numbers and if a value does not exist display the number with a blank line next to value in the HTML Table

Tags: php, html, mysql

PHP and MYSQL: select values between two numbers and  if a value does not exist display the number with a blank line next to value in the HTML Table

I am honestly stuck I have tried to do this so many different ways without any success that I am starting think it is impossible.

I have a HTML Table that is compiled from a MYSQL query and displayed by with php. Currently I look for all the values between 1 and 15 and then fill the table with the results. The problem however is there is not always 15 results in the query and the missing ones needs to be written in by hand. Now when the table is generated in HTML there are numbers missing. I am trying to get a blank line with only the number and space to write on a printed page. I when I do a if statement and lets say there is 10 entries I get 10 blank lines below every line that is generated. Any advice on how to achieve this will be appreciated. Here is the code.

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('
SELECT id
     , team_select
     , player_pic 
     , Surname
     , Name
     , LEFT(Name , 1) as Initial 
     , reg_no 
     , DOB
     , Age 
  FROM players 
 WHERE Club = "Bobbies" 
   AND age_group = "o/10" 
   AND team_select BETWEEN 1 AND 15 
 ORDER 
    BY LPAD(lower(team_select), 10,0) ASC
 ');
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        extract($row);

        ?>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
<tr>

<td style="line-height: 14px";><?php echo $team_select; ?></td>
<td style="line-height: 14px";><img src="user_images/<?php echo         
$row['player_pic']; ?>"   height="40px"/></td>
<td style="line-height: 14px";><?php echo $pos_name; ?></td>
<td style="line-height: 14px";><?php echo $Surname; ?></td>
<td style="line-height: 14px";><?php echo $Initial; ?></td>
<td style="line-height: 14px";><?php echo $Name; ?></td>
<td style="line-height: 14px";><?php echo $reg_no; ?></td>    
<td style="line-height: 14px";><?php echo $DOB; ?></td>
<td style="line-height: 14px";><?php echo $Age; ?></td> 
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>

</tr>
</div>      
        <?php
    }
}
else
{
    ?>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; No         Data Found ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}

?>
```

[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQsSI.jpg)

Comment: This is not impossible. You can do it with SQL or PHP. Which would you prefer?

Comment: Either is fine I just need to get this to work in some way or the other, at least I know I am not going insane.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do it (not tested):

We know we need 1 through 15

```
$min = 1;
$max = 15;
```

And we know we may not have any results

```
$results = array();
```

Then what I would do is first put all of your rows in an array, instead of trying to output them directly to the table:

```
if( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 )
{
    while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) )
    {
        $results[] = $row;
    }
}
```

Now, since you have an unknown amount of results, we do something like this:

```
$final_arr = array();

for( $x = $min; $x <= $max; $x++ )
{
    $found = FALSE;

    foreach( $results as $result )
    {
        // I used team select here, only because it seemed logical based on your query, but you might need to change that.
        if( $result['team_select'] == $x )
        {
            $final_arr[$x] = $result;
            $found = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }

    if( $found === FALSE )
    {
        // This is your placeholder row
        $final_arr[$x] = array(
            'id'          => '',
            'team_select' => '',
            'player_pic'  => '',
            'Surname'     => '',
            'Name'        => '',
            'Initial'     => '',
            'reg_no'      => '',
            'DOB'         => '',
            'Age'         => ''
        );
    }
}
```

Now you have a final array you can loop through and create your table rows

```
foreach( $final_arr as $row_number => $row_array )
{
    // Fill in your table rows
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this and give feedback.

Comment: Thanks this still returned the same set of results.

Comment: In your original question you say, "Now when the table is generated in HTML there are numbers missing". What field in the DB table is your number?

Comment: the team_select field has the numbers so if there is player 1,3,4 I need a empty line for 2 but it still just shows 1,3,4. When I do get it to generate the empty line, it shows record 1 once 2 empty lines record 3 three times and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it using SQL.

I made this simple table to illustrate how it would work.  The idea is that if a team is missing, then return an empty row so that no team is missing from the output.

```
CREATE TABLE `players` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `teamId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

In the players table I put this:

```
INSERT INTO `players` (`id`, `teamId`, `name`)
VALUES
(1, 1, 'Harry'),
(2, 3, 'Flynn'),
(3, 4, 'Connick'),
(4, 5, 'Kelly'),
(5, 7, 'Davis');
```

Then run this query: (replace with your actual query)

```
SELECT tmp.teamId, `players`.name FROM `players`
RIGHT JOIN 
(SELECT teamId
FROM (
              SELECT 1 AS teamId
UNION ALL     SELECT 2
UNION ALL     SELECT 3
UNION ALL     SELECT 4
UNION ALL     SELECT 5
UNION ALL     SELECT 6
UNION ALL     SELECT 7
UNION ALL     SELECT 8
UNION ALL     SELECT 9
UNION ALL     SELECT 10
UNION ALL     SELECT 11
UNION ALL     SELECT 12
UNION ALL     SELECT 13
UNION ALL     SELECT 14
UNION ALL     SELECT 15
) as t) AS tmp ON (tmp.teamId = `players`.teamId)
ORDER BY tmp.teamId
```

Produces the following output:

```
1   Harry
2   NULL
3   Flynn
4   Connick
5   Kelly
6   NULL
7   Davis
8   NULL
9   NULL
10  NULL
11  NULL
12  NULL
13  NULL
14  NULL
15  NULL
```

From there you can get the rows back and detect the empty rows.